# how to process external events using async await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, async-await, message-queue

Traditional code pattern for event-driven architecture is to wire-up events to functions (callbacks) and react to external triggers.

One of the advantages of aysnc await is code that processes linearly for better readability.

The following code reacts to externally triggered events by placing tasks on a message-queue and then in a master loop pull & process ( I guess for highly scalable this should be separate process ).

I'm not quite seeing how to refactor use of a message-queue to async await external events ( if that's even advisable ).

```
public class QueueProcessor
{
    public SomeMessageQueue MQ;
    public delegate void ExternalNotificationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ExternalNotificationHandler ExternalNotify;

    public QueueProcessor()
    {
        // configure MQ
        ExternalNotify += ProcessExternalNotification;
    }

    public void ProcessExternalNotification(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create new task and add to message queue
    }

    public void ProcessTasks()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // pull tasks off message queue and process
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So to better understand you, what do you actually want to make async here? is it the case you want an async call back system. can you briefly explain the use case, and what you want to use the async await pattern for

Comment: replace message-queue with async-await

Comment: Have you looked into TPL Dataflow, or reactive extensions? this could be were you are heading with this in the end

Comment: I'm brand new to reactive extensions - specifically what should I dig into ?

Comment: its a set of tools to operate on sequences of data regardless of whether the data is synchronous or asynchronous. DataFlow, is a set of tools to arrange data into pipelines for processing

Answer (score 2):

> Traditional code pattern for event-driven architecture is to wire-up events to functions (callbacks) and react to external triggers.
>
> One of the advantages of aysnc await is code that processes linearly for better readability.

Both of these are true, but these are fundamentally different. The difference is between a "push" system and a "pull" system. In a "push" system, your application receives events coming in and has to respond to them. In a "pull" system, your application reaches out to some external system and pulls data in.

Push-based systems include event-driven architecture and System.Reactive (Reactive Extensions / Rx).

Pull-based systems include `async`/`await` and the upcoming "async streams".

There's nothing wrong with using events (or Rx) to handle push-based events. I wouldn't change the code just to "use `async`". However, some code can be better understood when written from a pull-based orientation, and in this case you can create a bridge.

In order to bridge between push and pull, you need some kind of buffer or backpressure system. There are several such systems available, e.g., System.Threading.Channels and TPL Dataflow, and some Rx operators. So you could, e.g., have an event (push-based) that writes messages into a Channel that buffers each message, and have a separate `async` reader (pull-based) that reads those messages from the Channel and processes them.